# Button controlled functions to create list items, populate them, then edit. curious errors occurring. code and comments inside

Tags: javascript, nodes, createelement

The issues are coming up in the last function which serves to edit the lists as needed

[JSBin Link](https://jsbin.com/fiwowusesu/edit?html,js,output)

code:

```
// function to edit the desired list item with user input text
function editAList(){
   var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   var uList = document.getElementById("List");
   var listLength = list.length; // not needed at the moment
   var listNum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the list number you would like to edit. Any number from 1 to "+listLength))-1;
   var edit = document.createTextNode(prompt("Enter the new list text"));
   uList.replaceChild(edit, uList.childNodes[listNum]);   
}
```

Issue 1:

the `editAList` function works ONLY for number 0 [technically 1 because I have a subtraction built in for a user who doesn't know it starts at 0] on user input for 'listNum'. Any other value returns error 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.'

Attempts to fix 1:

Have tried 'parseInt' to convert to a number (despite my understanding that JS is a "loose script" language that doesn't need this sort of formatting). 
Have also tried 'document.createTextNode(prompt(...));' as well and received same error message.

Issue 2:

It erases the list item and replaces with just the 'edit' text

Attempts to fix 2:

Have tried putting `document.createElement("li")` within the `createTextNode` argument - resulted in printing OBJECT HTML LI 
Tried placing it before and after the createTextNode method but it generated error of 'i'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use edit function as:

```
function editAList(){
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var uList = document.getElementById("List");
    var listLength = list.length;
    var listNum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the list number you would like to edit. Any number from 1 to "+listLength))-1;
    var edit = document.createTextNode(prompt("Enter the new list text"));
    list[listNum].innerHTML="";
    list[listNum].appendChild(edit);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked - gave you answer credit. If you don't mind answering a followup question. What does 'list[listNum].innerHTML=" ";' do here? I see that it fixes the issue but I don't understand enough JS to know why.

Comment: Thinking about it now. Is it replacing the text with a space and then appending the edit to the list?

Comment: @vampiire you are right,it is so that edited text do not get appended to the previous one.

Comment: Nothing great:)